# How to export a 2D stabilized movie clip?

Tags: rendering, tracking

So, in the default view, I switched the 3D main view to "Movie Clip Editor".

I then added a video clip, made a bit of 2D image stabilization on it.
I'm happy with what I have now, and I'd like to save it to an output file.

In the properties, I've set start frame to 1, end frame to the ending frame of the video clip. In Post Processing, both Compositing and Sequencer is ticked. Output is set to h.264, etc.

Now, When I click "Animation" in the Render menu, It renders an empty, gray image, that is as long as I selected, but is not the video clip I've been editing.

So, how do I do that?

Also: Suppose I want to use that finished (stabilized) clip in the sequence editor, how do I put that clip into the sequence editor? The only way I can add clips like that, seems to be just adding the original source movie, but I want the clip I've been working on. How do I do that?

Comment: Is "sequencer" checked under post-processing in the render settings?

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ In the render settings? I can only find them in the Properties window, under Post Processing. And yes, it is ticked as I explained in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired, I missed that int he original post, I read it over twice to check for it too . . . My other suggestion is check your renderlayer settings

Comment: Have you setup the compositing nodes?

Comment: I recommend you post the blend file, I guess we can exchange your clip by another if your clip is excessive big for upload.

Comment: @sambler erm, I don't know what you mean. Perhaps that's the problem? I didn't set up anything besides my video and the video properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After setting up and tracking a video in the movie clip editor, you will want to use the tracking data to export an altered video. The adjusted video you see in the clip editor is only an in-memory adjusted version for feedback purposes.

To get a final adjusted video output you will need to setup some compositing nodes to adjust the "rendered" output. The minimum setup you will want is a movie clip input node, a 2D stabilization node and a composite node, a viewer node will let you preview the result behind the nodes if you enable the backdrop option.

[image: stablisation nodes]

Of course you can also add any other nodes to this for colour correction or adding 3D objects etc.

Now when you press render the result will match what is connected to the composite node.

Comment: I cannot use that clip in the sequencer right away, can I? I have to render the video first, and then use it to put into the sequencer as a strip, right?

Comment: You should be able to add a scene strip and see the composited result in the VSE.

Answer (score 3):

Go into a *Video Sequence Editor* and add your Movie Clip via *Add* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) > ***Clip...*** > *<name_of_your_clip>* at Frame 1.

In the *Filter* Properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) Panel of your Clip you can check *Stabilize 2D Clip* and *Undistort Clip* if needed.

Comment: But this will only do a 100% stable and not take into account properties like the new expected offset.